# Equal Column Heights using CSS online

Tags: html, css

So I have created an example in JSFiddle which is layered out similar to a table, row and cells however which I'm trying to make so the columns are all equal height but as you can see from the white background on each column this is not really working out.

I want to avoid a JS solution and know its possible in CSS but I think I'm just missing something.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/6swpqhuf/1/

CSS:

```
body {
    background: black;
}
div.table {
    display: table;
}
div.row {
    display: table-row;
    clear: both;
}
div.col {
    display: table-cell;
    background: white;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: Take off `float: left;`, this isn't needed when you are using `display: table-cell;` [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6swpqhuf/2/)

Comment: or change row display to `flex` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6swpqhuf/3/)

Comment: removing float seemed to have done the trick but removed all the margins.... any ideas with that? thanks for your help.

Comment: @James `margin` cannot work with `table-cell`.

Comment: Ahh managed to crack it with flex and no float, thanks guys!

Comment: @James Good stuff, I think flex is a bit limited on IE so you may want to check that but it works great on most modern browsers.

Comment: You can use border spacing on the table instead of margin: https://jsfiddle.net/6swpqhuf/5/

Comment: I dont want to apply to whole table just the :nth-child(3n-1) on the columns with left and right of 20px is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comment. As you can see in your code you have `float: left;` why is this here? `display: table-cell;` is already putting them in the same row for you.

Just remove this and it will fix your layout.

```
div.col {
    display: table-cell;
    background: white;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6swpqhuf/2/)

Comment: Only issue im facing is setting margin now on the middle cell with :nth-child(3n-1) - i just want to apply margin left and right at 20px any ideas around this?